# How to change this do block to original monad code?

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
loop height weight=do
line<-getLine
if line=="1" then
    do
        height<-getLine
        loop height weight
else if line=="2" then
    do 
        weight<-getLine
        loop height weight
    else if line=="3" then
        do
            putStrLn (height)
        else
            do
                putStrLn "error"
```

someone told me there is so much "do",I try to change this code not to use "do":

```
loop height weight=
getLine>>=(\line->(
if line=="1" then
    getLine>>=(\height->
    loop height weight
else if line=="2" then
    getLine>>=(\weight->
    loop height weight
    else if line=="3" then
            putStrLn (height+weight)
        else
                putStrLn "error"))))
```

but the compiler told me there is some wrong on line if line=="2" and I can't fix it

can you teach me how to change this code without "do"?

Comment: Check the parity of your parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think using case of construct would make your code much clear, but this is just personal choice. Also putStrLn (height+weight) is incorrect, because height and weight are strings and your treating them as integers. Maybe you mean ++ ?

```
loop height weight =
  getLine >>= \line ->
  case line of
    "1" -> getLine >>= \height -> loop height weight
    "2" -> getLine >>= \weight -> loop height weight
    "3" -> putStrLn . show $ (read height :: Int) + (read weight :: Int)
    _ -> putStrLn "error"
```

Comment: Much better than the original code. One can also use `print` instead of `putStrLn . show`.